# Error creating flexipages

Tags: salesforce1-app, flexipages

I'm following the tutorial warehouse salesforce1 and I can't find where I can create flexipages, I tried to make deployment package as zip like in the tutorial but it does not get hit.

When I go to create -> tabs, not against guide as requested by the tutorial.

Could you help me please?

Comment: Are you having problems creating the page or deploying it?

Comment: I created the pages, but the IDE does not recognize. When I create the deploy, they are not available for publication.

Comment: It looks like the tutorial is walking you through how to deploy it using the workbench. I believe the process would be different for Eclipse.